# NetBeans: Is it possible to push a branch in git, with the option --force?

Tags: git, netbeans, push

At present branch i rebase with upstream and it done resulting in additional commit at the penultimate position.

At this point I can not normally push the branches, because I get the message no fast forward and everything falls :)

The solution is pushed out with option -- force. I've searched entire internet, all the forums but have not found information about the possibility of-force in netbeans. Is netbeans has this capability? or I can only choose the console?

Comment: Is this a single local commit that ended up in the middle of the remote commits? I don't think that you should push at all.

Comment: no no, I just wanted to highlight general reason of the whole event ... Generally speaking, I made the changes on the branch, but meanwhile I had to merge approved changes from github. Fetch, then rebase, and finally pushed out of the option - force. But how to do this in netbeans?

Comment: Well, as far as I know there is no way to do it directly through the netbeans UI (you can open a Terminal inside the IDE with `Window` -> `IDE Tools`-> Terminal).

Comment: Anyway, you should never ever have to do `push -f` in a normal flow. To avoid it, create the feature branch as you do today, only `pull` changes into `master`. Keep rebasing the feature branch on top of `master`. Just before pushing master, `pull` from the remote branch, rebase the feature branch on top of master and merge the feature branch into `master` (this will always be a `fast forward`)

Comment: If someone pushed a sneaky commit after you have merged the feature branch back on `master` but before you have issued a `push` to the remote repository (unlikely, but can happen); do the following: `revert` master to how it was before the `merge`, `pull` the new commit, `rebase` the feature branch on top of master again, `merge` the feature into master and `push` immediately. This article gives a nice intro about the subject http://rypress.com/tutorials/git/rebasing.html

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated by [issue 213855](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=213855), you can, since NetBeans 7.4+, do a `pull --rebase`.
([Netbeans pull](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html#pull))

That is safer than trying to force a push, potentially overriding history that other depends on and would already have fetched.